# spring url mapping when @PathVariable is empty

Tags: spring

For the following url mappings (all GET requests):

```
1. "/book/{book-id}"

2. "/book/publisher/{publisher-id}"

3. "/book/borrower/{borrower-id}"
```

If **2.** or **3.** are called with empty string e.g. /book/publisher/ or /book/user/ then the forward slash / is ignored and **1.** is invoked with book-id as 'publisher' or 'borrower'. Is this a correct behaviour because a path variable is mandatory rendering 1 as the only valid url in this situation, or is there some config that controls it?

This is a simple rest controller that returns JSON (code simplified):

```
@RestController
public class BookController {

@Autowired
BookRepository repository; //JPA repository

@RequestMapping(value="/book/{book-id}",method= RequestMethod.GET)
public Book getBook(@PathVariable("book-id") String bookId){
    return repository.findOne(bookId);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/book/publisher/{publisher-id}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Book> getBooksByPublisher(@PathVariable("publisher-id") String publisherId){
    return repository.findAll(publisherId);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/book/borrower/{borrower-id}",method= RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Book> getBooksForBorrower(@PathVariable("borrower-id") String borrowerId){
   return repository.findAll(borrowerId);
}
}
```

Comment: please post your controller methods annotated with the request mapping as well

Comment: This is a correct behaviour. If a value is supposed to be null, pass it as a parameter and not a path.

Comment: I'm asking because I am writing tests for this controller and was stuck on this issue :)

Comment: I think you should check this: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-pattern-comparison

Answer (score 0):

You can control the flow like this in your getBook() method

```
if(bookId.equals("publisher") || bookId.equals("borrower")){
        model = new ModelAndView("index");
        //or do other code to controll the flow
        return model;
    }
```